# Printing array obtained as a return value C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, function-pointers

I am new to C++ and trying to understand application of pointers and passing and returning arrays as argument.

In this code I have an **array named ARR1** which is passed to **function copy()** as an argument this function **prints ARR1** and **creates ARR2**(copy of ARR1) which is **returned to main().**
**inside main()** function i am trying to **print arr2 but its giving wrong output.**
HERE IS THE CODE:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 
using namespace std; 
int * copy(int *x, int y) {
    int arr2[5] = {};
    cout << "Printing ARR1 \n";             
    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) {
         cout << *(x + i) << "\n";              //printing ARR1
         arr2[i] = x[i];                //assigning ARR1 values to ARR2
    }
    cout << "\n\n";
    return arr2;            //returning ARR2 to main()
}
int main() {
    int arr1[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int size = 5;           //size of arr1
    int *ans = copy(arr1 , size);           //obtaining ARR2 from copy()
    cout << "Printing ARR2 from MAIN() function\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {                
        cout << *(ans+i) << "\n";           //trying to print arr2 but its giving incorrect output.
    }
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT

```
Printing ARR1
1
2
3
4
5


Printing ARR2 from MAIN() function
-858993460
0
-858993460
6026436
6027184
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: you cant return an array from a function. Use either `std::array` (fixed size) or `std::vector` (dynamic size)

Comment: *undefined behavior* - you are returning a pointer to a function-local variable (whose life time ends when the function returns) -> You end up dereferencing a dangling pointer

Comment: @tobi303 im a totally new to c++ and dont know how to use std:array ??? can you give me the edited/corrected line of my code ?

Comment: btw, there are very different opinions on this, but if you are new to c++ you wont need raw pointers nor c-style arrays for quite some time and imho you could spend your time with more useful stuff (eg. the std algorithms library is worth to study in detail)

Comment: its not about a single line that can fix the code. Look at [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and you will find plenty of examples on how to use it